# Taking String arrays from different classes and passing it to different one

Tags: android, arrays

I have total three String arrays, two of them are in a class named as Homepage.java, and one of them is in Chatss.java, as follows -

Homepage.java code is as -

```
package com.md.viyo;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.provider.ContactsContract;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
  import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.TabHost;
   import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.CountCallback;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
 import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;


public class Homepage extends FragmentActivity implements     TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, Homepage.TabInfo>();
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
int j=0,i=0;
String[] fetch_name,fetch_num;
SharedPreferences prefs1, prefs, prefs2;
int tottal,ij=0, snumcount=0, snamecount=0, scloudcount=0;
Context mcontext;
/**
 *
 * @author mwho
 * Maintains extrinsic info of a tab's construct
 */
private class TabInfo {
     private String tag;
     private Class<?> clss;
     private Bundle args;
     private Fragment fragment;
     TabInfo(String tag, Class<?> clazz, Bundle args) {
         this.tag = tag;
         this.clss = clazz;
         this.args = args;
     }

}
/**
 * A simple factory that returns dummy views to the Tabhost
 * @author mwho
 */
class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}
/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "TUkcv3AsYpCAeZB1R6d5o3HvujUICdv9sqF4nMg5", "vBC4pyACIlwWxRmtqHriAJG2Jk3WFuF0X9bWpGyI");

    // Initialise the TabHost
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff9911")));
    bar.setIcon(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff9911")));
    //mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
   // mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(mTabHost.getCurrentTab()).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
    }
    // Intialise ViewPager
    this.intialiseViewPager();
    Cursor phones1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null );
    while(phones1.moveToNext())
    {
        j=j+1;
    }

    fetch_name = new String[j];
    fetch_num = new String[j];
    phones1.moveToFirst();
    while(phones1.moveToNext())
    {
        fetch_name[i]= phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        fetch_num[i] = phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        i =i + 1;
    }
    phones1.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ fetch_num.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
 */
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); //save the tab selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

/**
 * Initialise ViewPager
 */
private void intialiseViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Callss.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Chatss.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Contactss.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

/**
 * Initialise the Tab Host
 */
private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    Homepage.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Calls").setIndicator("Calls"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Calls", Callss.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    Homepage.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Chats").setIndicator("Chats"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Chats", Chatss.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    Homepage.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost.newTabSpec("Contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"), ( tabInfo = new TabInfo("Contacts", Contactss.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    // Default to first tab
    //this.onTabChanged("Tab1");
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        //mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")); // unselected
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title); //Unselected Tabs
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    }
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

/**
 * Add Tab content to the Tabhost
 * @param homepage
 * @param tabHost
 * @param tabSpec
 * @param clss
 * @param args
 */
private static void AddTab(Homepage homepage, TabHost tabHost, TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(homepage.new TabFactory(homepage));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

/** (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener#onTabChanged(java.lang.String)
 */
public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    //TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrolled(int, float, int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
        int positionOffsetPixels) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageSelected(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener#onPageScrollStateChanged(int)
 */
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.profile:
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected Phone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

in the above code two String Arrays are "fetch_name" & "fetch_num"
Now there is one more String Array as "cloud_num" 
its code is as follows -

```
package com.md.viyo;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.CountCallback;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

public class Chatss extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
String[] cloud_num;
String sss;
SharedPreferences spref1;
aint ij=0;
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chatss, container, false);
    spref1 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("con", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    sss = spref1.getString("conno", "nai");
    final ParseObject po = new ParseObject("Register");
    loadone(sss);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    loadtwo(sss);
    return v;
}

private void loadone(String sss1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> hue = ParseQuery.getQuery("Register");
    hue.whereNotEqualTo("contact",sss1);
        hue.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {

            @Override
            public void done(int tottal, ParseException arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (arg1!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please try after some time..." , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {

                    cloud_num = new String[tottal];

                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + tottal, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }); 
        hue.cancel();   
}
private void loadtwo(String sss2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> quee = ParseQuery.getQuery("Register");
    quee.whereNotEqualTo("contact",sss2);
    quee.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> oobid, ParseException arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (arg1!=null)
{
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+arg1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{

    for(ParseObject register : oobid){
        cloud_num[ij] = register.getString("contact").toString();
        ij=ij+1;
    }

    }
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "i" + cloud_num.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

        }

    }); 
quee.cancel();
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ho gya", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public String[] getcnum()
{
    return(cloud_num);
}
```

}
And i want these three String Arrays values in another class named as Contactss.java -

Contactss.java is as follow -

```
    package com.md.viyo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class Contactss extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment 
{
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contactss, container, false);
    return v;
}


}
```

I have tried many methods for passing String Arrays but nothing helped me, please help me by providing me full code to pass String Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**One thing you can use `public Static` Keyword to your `string arrays` and call it in any class you want**

**or**

**SharedPrefernces**

**converting it into a string with delimiter and stroing in sharedprefernce**

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
        sb.append(playlists[i]).append(",");
    }
    prefsEditor.putString(PLAYLISTS, sb.toString());
```

**At retreiving end**

```
String[] playlists = playlist.split(",");
```

Comment: you mean i have to declare String Arrays as public static? if yes, so how to call that string array in another class?

Comment: (Class Name).stringName like in your case `Chatss.cloud_num`

Answer (score 0):

Declare these two methods in first class:

```
public static String[] fun1(){return fetch_name;}
public static String[] fun2(){return fetch_num;}
```

Same way declare another method in the second class with the same method signature. Only change the function name as per will and the String array variable name which you return.

```
public static String() fun3{return cloud_name);
```

In the third class, do this:

```
String [] names= Homepage.fun1();
String [] num= Homepage.fun2();
String [] cname= Chatss.fun3();
```

All of the three above lines need to be written in a function. You may declare the String[] variables in the class itself already. I hope I'm clear enough. Post a comment if you have any doubt.

Comment: By using this method you wouldn't have to declare your string variables publicly. Also, it'd save you from a complicated code required to do such an easy task.